# ajax in php loop perform action on button click

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

so i have a php loop, i am using jquery slide toggle to hide/show a table with sql results. currently the table is loaded using php only, but as there is a lot going on its causing some loading problems i need to fire the ajax with the slide toggle btn, so it only requests the current items details when the button is pressed. i can get it to call the php file from the jquery but im having difficulty passing the value for each item across, so it can perform the request on the database. here is what the php foreach loop content looks like;

```
<span class="searchitem">
  // some visible content here 
  <span value="item name" class="btn">button</span>
  <span class="slide_area">
    // hidden slide content ajax needs to populate with php result
  </span>
</span>
```

this html is repeated i use jquery slidetoggle to hide the slide_area, what i need to do is populate the slide_area with results from php, the php file needs the name to return the results the name is passed via get with the url, so i only need append the url with the actual name from btn's value, im sure this cant be that difficult but here i am.

here's the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[  
    $(document).ready(function ()
              {
                    $('.searchitem').each(function () {
                        $(this).find('.slide_area').hide();
                        $(this).find('.btn').click(function ()
                        {
                            var ajax_load = "<img src='images/spinner.gif' style='width:50px;' alt='loading...' />";  
                            var loadUrl = "ajax/item.php?name=";    
                            var loadName = $(".btn");
                            var Name = URLEncode(loadName);
                            var loadString = loadUrl + Name;
         $(this).parent().find('.slide_area').slideToggle(1500).html(ajax_load).load(loadString);
                        });
                    });
              });
 //]]>
 </script>
```

i need to get the value from btn and append the loadURL, im open to sending the data a different way like through post if needed, updated the jquery still not working what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Dude, your '.' (dot) key must be broken because there's none of it in your text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would to use the Phery library http://phery-php-ajax.net/
the key here is the `data-phery-remote="toggle"` that will call the PHP function automatically on click, and can be reused everywhere

```html
<span class="searchitem">
  // some visible content here 
  <span value="item name" data-phery-remote="toggle" class="btn">button</span>
  <span class="slide_area">
  // hidden slide content ajax needs to populate with php result
  </span>
</span>
```

The logic is reversed, the load will happen with only one AJAX call, instead of two.

```php
Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'toggle' => function($data){
    $r = new PheryResponse;
    /* do your code, fill $html_content */
    $r->this()->siblings('.slide_area')->html($html_content)->toggle();
    return $r;
  }
))->process();
```